# How can I set a conditional statement to check what's the type of the object that called a method in java

Tags: java, oop

I have in my main class an instance of an object from another class (class name's dog) (which is a child class of another one) that's calling a method from its super class (whose name's animal), and I want that method, located in the super class, to verify what's the object's type that is making the call, like the code below. Is there a way to do that?

```
public class Main {
   Dog dog = new Dog();
   dog.sleep();
}

class Dog extends Animal{}

class Animal {
    int size;
    String color;
    double weight;

    void sleep(){
    THIS IS HOW I WANTED IT TO WORK:
    if (calling object is of type "dog" == true){
       System.out.println("Dog is Sleeping");
    }

    void run(){
        System.out.println("Running");
    }

}
```

Comment: Though you can do this, you shouldn't. _Override_ the method in `Dog` instead.

Comment: ```this instanceOf Dog``` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Animal {
int size;
String color;
double weight;

void sleep(){
  System.out.println("Running");
}

void run(){
    System.out.println("Running");
}
}

class Dog extends Animal{
   void sleep(){
     System.out.println("Dog is sleeping.");
   }
}
```